# Editing CSS by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to edit my root in CSS by JS with the inputs from HTML, but for sure, it is not working.

I linked them in HTML by link href and script src

```js
var VarRTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC').value
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--oneStroke", VarRTGCLC + "px")

//OR

// let root = document.documentElement;
// root.style.setProperty(VarRTGCLC + "px")
```

```css
:root {
  --oneStroke: 2px;
}

.RTGCLC {
  stroke-width: var(--oneStroke) !important;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>kresba plicní</td>
  <td><input id="RTGCLC" name="RTGChestLungCong" value="10" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this

Your statement works, you just need to execute it on an event. Here I use the `input` event of the input field you have

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("RTGCLC").addEventListener("input", function() {
    const VarRTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC').value
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--oneStroke", VarRTGCLC + "px")
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --oneStroke: 2px;
}

.RTGCLC {
  stroke-width: var(--oneStroke) !important;
  stroke: green;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-opacity: 1
}
```

```html
Velikost čar: <input type="number" id="RTGCLC" value="2" />


<svg height="300px" width="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
 <path class="RTGCLC" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"  /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, I will repeat myself. I have some inputs at HTML, those inputs must change the stroke-width, it can only change by CSS and i need those inputs load at JS and then edit the ":root" by JS.

<path
         class="RTGCLC"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```js
var VarRTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC');
```

Try:

```js
var VarRTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC').value;
```

### Update

I noticed that you don't have buttons or listeners:

You can add one by adding a `button` element.

```html
<button onclick="update">Update</button>
```

and in JS:

```js
function update() {
    var VarRTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC')
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--oneStroke", VarRTGCLC + "px")
}
```

That should do the work.

Comment: Still nothing, it maybe takes now value, but won't to rewrite in the root.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```js
let RTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ChangeSize(){
var VarRTGCLC = document.getElementById('RTGCLC').value
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--oneStroke", VarRTGCLC + "px")
}


//OR

// let root = document.documentElement;
// root.style.setProperty(VarRTGCLC + "px")
```

```css
:root {
  --oneStroke: 2px;
}

.RTGCLC {
  stroke-width: var(--oneStroke) !important;
  border:1px solid #bbb
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>kresba plicní</td>
  <td><input id="RTGCLC" name="RTGChestLungCong" value="10" onChange="ChangeSize()" /></td>
</tr>
```

Try this i think it works for you